# Best way to getting users geolocation into php without page reload

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

I am currently stuck with processing the lat/long into my PHP code. 
When the users makes a selection in a select-box a script is run which returns the geolocation.
My first attempt was to save the lat/long in a JavaScript cookie and read the cookie from PHP. This works, but only when the page is reloaded. But I need the lat/long in my SQL query which is run when the users clicks the button.
I haven't used AJAX yet, so if there is any other possibility I would be more than happy to hear!

Thanks!

Comment: AJAX seems the most reasonable option here.

Comment: @MaximKhan-Magomedov I was afraid that someone would say this :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well basically, no. PHP will be executed only on your server, so the data of the geolocation of the browser somehow must be transmitted to the server somehow. As you can only send data to the server by a HTTP request, you have to reload the page or use AJAX.

However if you only want an imprecise geolocation, you might guess the location by the ip of the user ( for example the page http://www.ip2location.com has implemented such an location "finder" ). However is based on the fact, that ip-address-ranges are often hosted by the same provider, in the same area. Also this method behaves incorrect, if somebody is using a proxy.

For Ajax I would propose JQuery. In JQuery it is relatively simple to create AJAX requests:

```
$.get('example/myDoc.txt', function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

This example is taken from http://www.jquerysample.com/#BasicAJAX and would request the servers example/myDoc.txt file.

Comment: Hi again! Would the best way be to make an AJAX call to a php file which sets the cookie instead?!

Comment: That depends on what you exactly want to do. If your doing an AJAX call to a php file, in the php file you might check if the cookie is already set. And run the corresponding php-code exactly once. If you do this in javascript/ajax, you could do the same, check there if the cookie is already set and if not sent an Ajax-request to your server.

However keep in mind, that Javascript in the browser and PHP on your server, so PHP code slows down your server and your JS code might not be executed out of user specific settings etc.

Comment: Thanks! I just want to have the lat/long available on the original page without reloading.